# Override the Class function in wordpress theme functions file

Tags: wordpress, function, themes, overriding, woocommerce

I need help for override the Class function in wordpress theme functions file.
I am using woocommerce plugin for my website and I want override the  “download_product” function in theme functions file from “WC_Download_Handler” class.

Please give me the correct syntax so it will work, I have tried multiple way but it’s not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Changing the core woocommerce files is not recommended. Finding the hook or filter is the best way to modify functionality. But the documentation of Woocommerce hooks and filters is not that great.

What I usually do for my projects is to copy th Woocommerce template files to my theme directory and modify the files from there. That way you don't have to worry about Woocommerce being updated and your changes being lost.

Answer (score 0):

you cant override functions in your child theme or elsewhere.

Your options are to look for an hook the function is hooked into and `remove_action()` on the original function.

If there is no hook, you need to delete the function in woo commerce, you can replace with your own. you'll have to do this everytime you update.

You can override class methods, but of course you would need to extend the object and use the new object in place of the original!